# Remove invalid characters from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I have some content in my html page that I get into my javascript code like this:

```
var content = ele.innerHTML;
```

I send this content via a web service to my application and then later get the content back in a javascript string, like this:

```
var content = '<div>some html content here</div>';
```

The problem is, some times the "innerHTML" contains illegal characters and I end up with an illegal javascript string, giving me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` whenever I load the page.

For performance reasons, I want to fix this before saving the content in javascript. I figure it should be possible to detect in javascript, since javascript knows it doesn't like those illegal characters.

Obviously, this is a known problem, I've found many mentions of it. However, the solutions I found are all about just taking the first 128 or 255 characters of a character table and I think this would filter away way too many characters. I want to keep all the 'weird' but legal characters and only skip the illegal ones.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking to simply strip html tags - take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: No, I'm talking about illegal tokens, such as a zero-width space and other strange and invisible characters that can cause problems in Javascript.